# Is there a quick and dirty way to truncate a Waterline collection?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm constructing test plans for model service providers, and I want to load test data (just using a memory adapter) before the test (relatively easy), but is there a quick and dirty way to truncate all the collections after each test suite is finished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you not just do a remove all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either delete all the records or just call `.drop()` on a collection.

```
// Remove all records
User.destroy({}).exec(/** **/);

// Drop the collection
User.drop(function(err) { /** **/ });
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit hairy running multiple tests because of the `.initiliaze` method. Is this the best place to post an example to review, or should I use the Waterline issue tracker on Github?

Comment: *** Caution *** Dropping the collection will delete the table, and on production will not recreate the collection.

Answer (score 0):

With the sails-memory database, you can do this:

```
  sails.once('hook:orm:reloaded', done);
  sails.emit('hook:orm:reload');
```

See full [bootstrap.test.js](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/2016/06/sailsjs-testing-patterns-trunctate-database/).